# Can I edit any phtml file and not clear the cache?

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, phtml, pagespeed

Whenever I want to edit some phtml file, then I have to clear the cache. Is there anything to clear the cache or clean specific cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rub below command and then try

```
php bin/magento cache:disable block_html
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After run above commands you not need to clean or flush cache after update the phtml files